# function pointer handling in Doxygen in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, doxygen

In my code, a vtable containts several function pointer.
Doxygen is unable to follow them.

I'd like to force it to recognize the possible paths, to produce a complete Call Graph, since now this part is missing.

example:

```
typedef Bool(*SPECIAL_FUNC)(KEY key);

typedef struct{
  int a;
  int b;
  SPECIAL_FUNC;
}OBJ;

Bool add(KEY key); //code...
Bool sub(KEY key); //code...
```

Comment: Doxygen performs (simple) static analysis; how could it know what values your pointers take at run-time?

Comment: you're right. I don't want to see in the docs how it work in run-time. I want something like int add() int sub() showned in the doc where I have the function pointer so I can jump to the correct doc page

Comment: But how can it know what the possible paths are?

Comment: well... do you know a way for tell doxygen to tell it which possibilities I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this will likely not affect the call graph in doxygen, you can document the functions as related to the structure, and provide links to them in the documentation for `SPECIAL_FUNC`. Something like:

```
typedef Bool(*SPECIAL_FUNC)(KEY key);

/**
 * struct description
 */
typedef struct{
  int a;
  int b;

  /**
   * Function pointer to one of the following:
   * - add()
   * - sub()
   */
  SPECIAL_FUNC;
}OBJ;

/**
 * @relates OBJ
 * add function.
 */
Bool add(KEY key); //code...

/**
 * @relates OBJ
 * sub function.
 */
Bool sub(KEY key); //code...
```

With this, `OBJ` will be documented as a class, `add` and `sub` will appear as related members of `OBJ`, and the documentation for `SPECIAL_FUNC` will contain links to `add` and `sub`.

Comment: That's great, really what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your assistance. I spent much time googling for a solution but I did't find anything that could help me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this but one way of faking this could be to have special define just for this and only set it on for Doxygen (with PREDEFINED).

E.g.

```
#ifdef MY_DOXYGEN_FAKE
  KEY key;
  add(key);
  sub(key);
#endif
```

In functions where you use that function pointer. Of course it's more work since you have to make sure to only add calls to functions that you really use from that function. But then again you *should* know how that function pointer is used in any case.

Comment: It was my first approach. I defined it in the same way but I think after some coding the #ifdef #endif solution could give some trouble if you need to update your code in many places in different files. The solution posted by DRH is more cleaner. By the way... thank you for your help too :)