# List of related functions for a structure in Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

I use Doxygen to generate an API documentation for one of my C projects. For each data structure in the project, there is a bunch of functions, which somehow work with the structure (like a C++ class and it's methods).

And I would like Doxygen to generate a list of these functions on the page with the details of the structure. Is that possible?

Just for an illustration, most of my structures and related functions look like this:

```
typedef struct foo {
    /* anything */
} foo_t;

foo_t *foo_create(int a);
void foo_free(foo_t *foo);
int foo_do_magic(foo_t *foo, int a, int b);
int foo_do_other_magic(foo_t *foo, int a);
```

In this case, I want to have a list of `foo_create`, `foo_free`, `foo_do_magic`, and `foo_do_other_magic` functions at the bottom of a page with the details of `foo_t` structure.  How can I do that?

**Edit**: The `\related` command does exactly what I want, but unfortunatelly I would need to attach this command to every function. For now, I am using `\defgroup`, which creates a separate page with the structure and related functions.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574946/function-pointer-handling-in-doxygen-in-c

Comment: Maybe had a look at the Grouping paragraph in the manual and at the command \addtogroup and friends.

Comment: @francis Unfortunately, \relates has to be added to every function, which is somehting I do not want to do. Otherwise it does the thing as I wanted.

Comment: @albert Grouping into modules work pretty well. I will probably stick with that, as it seems to be the simplest solution. Thanks!